# Using func_get_args to edit an array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I wish to use a function with an arbitrary number of arguments to edit an array.  The code I have so far is:

```
 function setProperty()
 {
  $numargs = func_num_args();
  $arglist = func_get_args();
  $toedit = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs-1; $i++)
  {
   $toedit[] = $arglist[$i];
   }
   $array[] = $arglist[$numargs-1];
 }
```

The idea of the code being I can do the following:

```
setProperty('array', '2nd-depth', '3rd', 'value1');
setProperty('array', 'something', 'x', 'value2');
setProperty('Another value','value3');
```

Resulting in the following array:

```
Array
(
    [array] => Array
        (
            [2nd-depth] => Array
                (
                    [3rd] => value1
                )

            [something] => Array
                (
                    [x] => value2
                )

        )

    [Another Value] => value3
)
```

The issue I believe is with the line:

```
$toedit[] = $arglist[$i];
```

What does this line need to be to achieve the required functionality?

Cheers,

Comment: Where should this array be stored during the subsequent calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to walk the path to the destination before storing the new value. You can do this with a reference:

```
function setProperty() {
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    if ($numargs < 2) return false; // not enough arguments
    $arglist = func_get_args();

    // reference for array walk    
    $ar = &$array;
    // walk the array to the destination
    for ($i=0; $i<$numargs-1; $i++) {
        $key = $arglist[$i];
        // create array if not already existing
        if (!isset($ar[$key])) $ar[$key] = array();
        // update array reference
        $ar = &$ar[$key];
    }

    // add value
    $ar = $arglist[$numargs-1];
}
```

But the question where this `$array` should be stored still remains.

Comment: Heh, undeletes, I wondered why the answer wasn't there when I started :) Nice to know we think almost alike in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
class foo {
private $storage;
function setProperty()
{
    $arglist = func_get_args();
    if(count($argslist) < 2) return false;
    $target = &$this->storage;
    while($current = array_shift($arglist)){
        if(count($arglist)==1){
             $target[$current] = array_shift($arglist);
             break;
        }
        if(!isset($target[$current])) $target[$current] = array();
        $target = &$target[$current];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using foreach to loop through your array first. Then to handle children, you pass it to a child function that will grab everything.

I also recommend using the function sizeof() to determine how big your arrays are first, so you'll know your upper bounds.

Comment: I think you mean to say, "any way".